# computer science "knowledge about IDSs"

Tags: computer-science

I need help anyone have any idea or knowledge about the "Intrusion Detection Systems or Intrusion Detection Techniques". At least ten systems/techniques. I would like to support me to improve my knowledge.

Comment: Excuse me? In what way do you think that this is an acceptable question for here?  Just because something is a question does not automatically mean you are allowed to ask it here.  Read the rules before you ask and try harder next time.

Answer (score -1):

is the least answer my question:

NIDS; Network (based) IDS

HIDS; Host (based) IDS

Anomaly detection

Misuse detection

False Positive

False Negative

Tripwire

Signature

Fragmentation attack

Protocol violation attack

DoS attack